# SAP Client unable to access server "Internal Error 1102 131-183"

Tags: sql, sapb1

I've been trying for a few days to work out what's wrong with connecting to our SAP server from a workstation installed with a client.

My setup:

server:

Win 2008 R2
SQL Server 2008 R2
SAP B1 8.82 PL 14

Workstation:

Win 7 64bit
SQL Native Client 2008 R2 (same as on the server as recommended)

Situation:

I can see the companies\DBs from the client side but when I enter the right credentials it stalls for a few seconds then throws out the dreaded "Internal Error 1102 131-183".

Firewall has been completely turned off.

Communication is working perfectly fine on all ports.

I made sure both TCPIP and Piping have been enabled on CLICONFG.

When using Process Monitor I noticed 2 missing keys the SAP Business One.exe attempts to access but fails as they do not exist:

HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\SAP\SAP Manage
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\CTF\KnownClasses

I have no idea where to get them from...

I'd appreciate all help I can get.

Thanks

Comment: You are trying to connecto to an SQL server using the SQL server client. In how far is this question related to SAP? And speaking of SAP, which product of that company are you referring to?